# Gazebo: Turtlebot dont drive straight forward/ Odometry wheel velocity

Tags: navigation, odometry, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Guys,

I have encountered the problem that my Turtlebot didn't drive really straight and he also have some problems with the rotation. After a short period the robot loose the straight path and he drifts away more and more. I use the turtlebot from the turtlebot package in gazebo.

I create a Twist msgs:
self.cmd_vel = rospy.Publisher('cmd_vel_mux/input/navi', Twist, queue_size=10)
and then i set a linear speed:
move_cmd = Twist()
move_cmd.linear.x = 0.1
move_cmd.angular.z = 0

Is there a way to drive straight with no deviation?

How can i publish the wheel velocity of my turtlebot maybe the wheels have a different velocity?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272581/gazebo:-turtlebot-dont-drive-straight-forward/-odometry-wheel-velocity/) by [Baumboon](https://answers.ros.org/users/32033/baumboon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 206 on 2017-10-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would use a feedback loop of some sort. Measure real speed vs commanded speed possibly?

---

Originally posted by [cmfuhrman](https://answers.ros.org/users/33793/cmfuhrman/) with karma: 200 on 2018-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0